# Credit card invalid in Google play registration

Tags: google-play

I tried hard but Google wallet registration showing me message of "invalid credit card" error. I tried using visa card and master card also but the problem is still the same. I think this problem is happening because I haven't enabled internet banking in both cards. Is this the problem or something else? My app is ready for launch, but I can't upload it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about your bank account details

Comment: more appropriate for webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.isaumya.com/paypal-google-wallet-indian-debit-card-support/ the link shows the picture of the list of the banks, but for quick reference i have attached the screen shot of the image in that link

[image]

the picture has the list of banks that accept..

Comment: Do not put other website content as a screenshot as an answer. This is violation of copyright.